# How do you use jQuery with Win8 in a Metro application?

Tags: jquery, windows-runtime

All over the net, I've seen that you can use jQuery with Metro in a Javascript app, but I haven't found any examples.

The problem I'm running into is that it Visual Studio says there's an invalid character on line 1, character 1 of jQuery's script.  That's the beginning the of license comment, obviously.

```
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character
File: ms-wwa://9fa409da-8869-421d-9a95-68ef5541152e-sxgejhq22jcna/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line: 1 column: 1
```

I get this same error for jQuery Mobile, and 2 custom scripts that I wrote from scratch.  My 2 scripts don't have a comment there.

I do not get this error on the scripts that came with the default project, default.js and homePage.js .  

The custom scripts were used to develop a web app on Mac OS X.  But the jQuery scripts were downloaded directly from jQuery's site on the Windows machine and never touched the Mac.

I've also tried saving jQuery in different encodings.  They started as 'UTF-8 without BOM' (which was supposed to be correct, apparently) and I tried UTF-8 and Ansi as well.

I even get this error when I add a Javascript file directly in Visual Studio, and only ever edit it from within VS.  I use a script tag that's identical to the one that loads the homePage.js script that works, but the new script has this error.

I've experimented more, and I think it might not be copying the file to the package.  If I rename homePage.js to homePage2.js it complains that it can't compile because it can't find homePage.js .  But I can't find anywhere to edit a list of files to package.

Final edit:  I started an entirely new project and slowly added things, and the problem doesn't exist for this new project.  Somehow, the original project must have been corrupt, somehow.  I'd still like to know what caused this, so I can fix it if happens again, but for now the solution:  Start a new project and scrap this one.

Comment: Have you tried it with release preview or RTM? There were issues with older versions but I have it working nicely on RTM (and RP)

Comment: As I said, a new project did not have this issue.  Since upgrading to a more recent version basically required I make my projects from scratch (too many changes), there's no way to know if this still happens in the new versions...  Unless someone else runs into it.

Comment: Check this blog: [Jquery in a Windows 8 application](http://blog.adamroderick.com/2011/09/jquery-in-a-windows-8-application/)